# Bootstrap for Next.Js Typescript app how to install

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, react-bootstrap

After seeing many post I couldn't figure it out how to proper install Bootstrap for a Next.Js Typescript app. It's the first time I am going to use Bootstrap with Typescript and I am not sure how to do it. I saw those commands:
npm i bootstrap, npm i react-bootstrap, npm install @types/bootstrap, I wonder if I should use these three or there is no need for some of them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76699367/1457459) it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and reading many similar posts I found the asnwer. It needs to be installed three dependencies.
npm i bootstrap
react-bootstrap
@types/react-bootstrap

I hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

npm install bootstrap@next

https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-next-js-de997371fd9c

Comment: thanks for your answer @Matthew , but does it work with Typescript??

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer. I've only used TypeScript a few times and never saw conflict between using .ts vs. .js, as long as I compiled TypeScript to JavaScript. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew I needed to add the dependency for Typescript