# Where to import bootstrap js file in next js 13 using new "app directory"

Tags: next.js, bootstrap-5, next.js13

I am using new app directory in next js 13 and when using bootstrap dropdown only the UI is working, js features of bootstrap are not working in it.
I tried importing js file in layout.tsx but it throws this error =>

> document not defined

[image]

**Layout.tsx**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import './globals.css';
import './styles/index.scss';

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Create Next App',
    description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang='en'>
            <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I defined null component with useEffect importing bootstrap js in seperate file with "use client" directive, and included that component in RootLayout:

**importBsJS.tsx**

```
'use client'
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function ImportBsJS() {
  useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

**layout.tsx**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import ImportBsJS from "@/components/importBsJS";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ImportBsJS />
        <div className="container-lg">{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that using the "dynamic" function works to import the Bootstrap CSS always and the Bootstrap JS only on the client side in Next.js 13 in the layout.tsx file:

```js
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

// import '../styles/globals.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicBootstrap = dynamic(
  () => require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'),
  { ssr: false }
);

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a "content flash" on page load where things are unformatted for a second?

Comment: This worked for me. @sprite7, it doesn't cause any FOUC because the CSS is imported directly into the markup and only the JS is dynamically loaded after rendering. So, this is the common pattern we are using on the client side anyway. Of course it requires to adhere some basic rules of progressive enhancement (e.g. no element visibility changes via JS onload)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to manually integrate the bootstrap JS (either via CDN, or better as self-hosted scripts) directly in your RootLayout, which is pretty solid and does work with server-rendered components as well.

This might look a little old-fashioned, but I preferred this way over the useEffect/dynamic approach since it is much more explicit and easier to control what is happening behind the scenes. It allows you to painlessly use bootstrap everywhere without worrying about SSR or CSR.

```js
import Script from 'next/script';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

export default function RootLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
        <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></Script>
        <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></Script>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};
```

Note: I used the locally installed CSS from node_modules here for convenience. In a common scenario one would put the CSS and JS into the "/public" folder and just include everything directly from there (also to ensure that JS and CSS versions stay in sync).

Comment: So does this mean that it would first render the root element, then add the js files? or will the js files be part of the project and get rendered before serving the page?

Answer (score 1):

When this fails server-side:

```
import * as Bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

you can replace it with the following:

*app/providers/bootstrap.js*

```
"use client"

import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Context = createContext(undefined)

function Providers({ children } {
  const [Bootstrap, setBootstrap] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!Bootstrap) {
      const BS = require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js")
      setBootstrap(BS)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ Bootstrap }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export const useBootstrap = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context)

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useBootstrap must be used inside BootstrapProvider")
  }

  return context
}


export default Providers
```

*app/layout.tsx*

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "../styles/_global.scss"

import { Metadata } from "next"

import BootstrapProvider from "@/providers/bootstrap"

export const metadata: Metadata = {}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <BootstrapProvider>
          {children}
        </BootstrapProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and use it like this in the client-side component:

*app/components/CollapsibleExample.js*

```
"use client"

import { useBootstrap } from "@/providers/bootstrap"

export default () => {
  const { Bootstrap } = useBootstrap()

  const toggle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    new Bootstrap.Collapse(`#collapse-id`).toggle()
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={toggle}>Toggle</a>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your children you used document object and this error happend because the page was rendred before you be in the browser so the document is undefind for fix this use `typeof document !== "undefind" && "do something"`

Comment: I tried this method,  unfortunately it did not work for me.